# how to use regular expression to find node and its offset in xml in java

Tags: java, regex

In java, I want to find `<to>...</to>` using regular expression and also the offset of Tove. In this example, I will find Tove and its offset is from 10 to 13.

```
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html

Comment: Don't parse XML using regular expressions or bad things will happen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: That Meta question is disputed: +77, -39. So it's not dead.

Comment: @Unihedron It's not dead, and not joke. Please read my question. I need preserve the offset, not just parsing.

Answer (score -1):

You could achive that goal by using document builder, and taking advantage of XML structure. This could work if you do not need to use a regular expression as a mandatory requirement.

```
InputStream origin = new FileInputStream(url);
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(origin);

//Obtain to tag element
Element toTag = originalDoc.getElementsByTagName("to").item(0);

//Obtain Tove value
String value = toTag.getNodeValue();
```

Comment: Yes @user2372074, I read your question. I quote you "In java, I want to find <to>...</to> using regular expression **AND** also the offset of Tove." I tried to help you with the first part of your AND statement. Sorry if it did not help you.